# Why do I have to render my Bundle Twice?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

In `MVC` project, I'm including necessary references for `validation` with:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

In my `_Layout` page. But, for example in my `Register` page, validation doesn't work unless I add this code to my `Register` page. In both cases, when I look at the source of my page I see the necessary references there.

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive-custom-for-bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```

So everything is working fine. It doesn't add references twice, but I couldn't figure out what is the difference ?

Here is my **Bundle** code:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
```

Note: I'm rendering several style bundles in my `_Layout` and it doesn't cause any problems.

Comment: Does your _Layout page have "@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)" in it?

Comment: @Nathan, No, I guess it was, but I delete it.

Comment: Without that "@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")" won't work

Comment: @Nathan, I tried and it doesn't make any difference

Comment: can you show your complete (relevant parts) Register page

Comment: @G.Stoynev I can but it's unnecessary,problem isn't about my register page.It's same in my other pages,for example edit profile,reset password etc.

Comment: Are you sure that all that pages use _Layout ? Do you only have problem with @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval") or maybe with all budles that you render on _Layout page ?

Comment: @user1285941 Yes, I'm sure.I'm rendering some style bundles in my layout and everything working fine

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I tried validating in my partial views.

From different posts my solution ended up like this:

in the partial views I surround my edit fields with a `<div id="#formDiv>` 
and add the script

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.validator.unobtrusive.addValidation("#formDiv");
    });
</script>
```

and a custom.js:

```
//Validation on partial views
    $(function () {
        $.validator.unobtrusive.addValidation = function(selector) {
            //get the relevant form 
            var form = $(selector);
            // delete validator in case someone called form.validate()
            $(form).removeData("validator");
            $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);
        };
    });
```